# Javascript- Multiplying 2 numbers and return number

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I normally have understood this stuff well as I am taking web programming for a non-major class and guess I am just a little confused on what I'm being asked to do.

I am told to "Write a function named "MULTIPLY" that accepts 2 parameters. the function will be declared this way:

```
function MULTIPLY(parameter1, parameter2){
    //The parameter names can be whatever you want 
    //Your code goes here

};
```

I have wrote this as my code :

```
function MULTIPLY (price, shipping) {
    return price*shipping;

    enter code here

    product=number1*number2;

    //return the result

    return total;
```

Comment: Your code is missing the `}` at the end. You also left in StackOverflow's `enter code here`. Please show what you actually wrote.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    function multiplyNumbers(x,y){
        return x*y;
    }
    var z= multiplyNumbers(4,5); // Function is called, return value will end up in z

</script>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('multiplication').innerHTML=z;">Multiply numbers</button>
<p id="multiplication"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems. Here is how it should look

```
function MULTIPLY(price, shipping) {
    //Return the sum
    return price*shipping;
}

//Call MULTIPLY to multiply the two numbers
var product=MULTIPLY(number1, number2);
```

Comment: Thank you DrRoach. What i also am very confused about is the //Some code part. Would that have something to do with the "return" function?

Comment: No not at all, that is simply any javascript code you want to do before you actually use the `MULTIPLY` function. The `//` indicate that it is a comment and that is never actually ran by the code.

Comment: I appreciate your feed back, so it would not be" //return the result" ?

Comment: No problem, and the comment will be anything that will explain the code. Look at the edit

Comment: Okay i am still not sure on what i would use

Comment: or is this something that wouldnt effect the grading of it, just something i name it?

Comment: No it wouldn't, it is simply to help[ you at a later date or to explain your code to another person reading it